# xamarin ios in app purchase with Xamarin.InAppPurchase component IPv6 issues

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

My app was rejected by apple, because they were unable to purchase content when they are connected to an IPv6 network. I didn't had to test the app in a IPv6 network, but on a normal network everything worked fine. I'm currently using the Xamarin.InAppPurchase (the current version 2.8) component. The error which occured when they pressed the purchase button was the standard error alert from the InAppPurchase component "Error while purchasing [...]". Anybody has the same problem, or a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go over this blog post about making Xamarin iOS Apps ipv6 ready?
https://blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready/

Among other things noted in the blog, the main issue seems to be using hard coded IPv4 addresses:

> All newly created IP Addresses will need to be IPv6 or converted to IPv6 if available. Our recommendation is to always use the hostname when possible, but if you are not able to, don’t fear, because it’s super simple with the .MapToIPv6() extension method. This is more of a quick fix, as you’ll never get a pure IPv6 connection; in this case you could also manually convert any IP to a byte array, or simply use IPAddress’s TryParse method to parse any IPv6 address. Additionally, check out some of the nifty methods in System.Net.Dns that can help resolve the IP Address for you if IPv6 is available or not. If you are using HttpClient, BasicHttpBinding, or WebRequests there are no changes needed unless using hard coded IP addresses as discussed above.